# After I switch default SSH ports, why does NMAP display port service as "down"

Tags: openssh, nmap

Running Ubuntu 13.04, I edit sshd_config to change `Port 22` to `Port 2022`

When I reload my sshd service and nmap the server from my local machine, I get this:

```
PORT     STATE SERVICE
2022/tcp open  down
```

What the!? Just trying to understand what's going on here.

Edit: I am still able to log in through `ssh auser@aserver -p2022`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Service` column in `nmap` is just what `nmap` thinks the service that is listening on that port is called.

If you had done a nmap when you had port 22 open, the service that would have shown up would have been `ssh`. Similar to this -

```
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
80/tcp   open  http
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize nmap just guessed service names, I thought sshd was actually down or something... -_-

Comment: It's not guessing.  `down` is the [IANA-registered Well Known Service](http://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/) on TCP port 2022.

Comment: An educated guess I suppose

Comment: More like an assumption.